# How can I call div tag element with another div tag element using onclick function

Tags: javascript, android, html, dom-events

I'm developing an application with Phonegap framework. I want to know how can I call one div tag element with another tag element using onclick Javascript function.

Here is my code:
I need to display second image onclicking the first image. (With CSS style class names:visible/invisible)

```
<div id="abc" class="visible">
<img style=" z-index:-1" src="icons/firstimage.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" border="0" alt="logo">
</div>

<div id="def" class="invisible">
<img style=" z-index:-1" src="icons/secondimage.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" border="0" alt="logo" >
</div>
```

Comment: What does it mean to call a div tag?  What are you trying to actually do?  And, where is the code you said you were including?

Comment: I am not able to see your code. Where you put it. Place your code then anyone can give you answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a javascript function on click and add class visible to the second div like below,

```
document.getElementById('def').className = 'visible';
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/nnFQV/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can just include regular JavaScript, below I'm using jQuery but that was just for my convenience.

```
<div onClick="$('#OtherDiv').html('you click')">test</div>
<div id="OtherDiv"></div>
```